# How can you get the number of parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, stored-procedures, parameters

How can i get the number of parameters that weree given to a `MS SQL` function or stored procedure?

Lets say mu function is:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.tst
    (
      @idINT ,
      @StartDate DATETIME ,
      @EndDate DATETIME
    )
...
```

When i call the function using `SELECT dbo.tst(1, '2015-11-11 23:14:45')` is there a way to determine that the function was called with only two parameters?

Edit:

Idealy I would like to have a funtion/sp that can coop with an unknow number of parameters, but as far as I know this is not possible.

The idea was to create a funtion with lets say 20 params and discover (count) the number of params passed into the function, so we can process only the values that were actually given to the funtion.

The bigger picture is implementing a hash funtion voor Data Vault 2.0 to create a hash value per record to discover changes. Since every table has a different number of fields, this can be chalanging. You do not want to create a funtion per table...

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

First of all with function  like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.tst(
      @idINT ,
      @StartDate DATETIME ,
      @EndDate DATETIME)

SELECT dbo.tst(1, '2015-11-11 23:14:45')
```

You will get:

> error An insufficient number of arguments were supplied for the
>   procedure or function dbo.tst.

One way is to add default parameter value like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.tst(
   @id INT,
   @StartDate DATETIME = NULL,
   @EndDate DATETIME = NULL)
```

but still you need to call it as:

```
SELECT dbo.tst(1, '2015-11-11 23:14:45', default)
```

with scalar function you can call it as:

```
EXECUTE dbo.tst 1, '2015-11-11 23:14:45'
```

I guess you want something like overloaded function in other programming languages. With functions you always need to specify all parameters.

With stored procedures you can use:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.tst(
      @idINT ,
      @StartDate DATETIME = NULL,
      @EndDate DATETIME = NULL)
AS 
BEGIN
   IF @StartDate IS NULL 
      -- user does not provide start date use default or do some operations
      -- SET @StartDate = ...
      ...

   IF @EndDate IS NULL
      ...

END;
```

Then you can reason about it:

```
EXEC dbo.tst 1, NULL, NULL
```

will be the same as:

```
EXEC dbo.tst 1
```

More info: **[`CREATE FUNCTION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx)**:

> When a parameter of the function has a default value, the keyword
>   DEFAULT must be specified when the function is called to retrieve the
>   default value. This behavior is different from using parameters with
>   default values in stored procedures in which omitting the parameter
>   also implies the default value. However, the DEFAULT keyword is not
>   required when invoking a scalar function by using the EXECUTE
>   statement.

Comment: thank you for the comment. Was not expecting it would go this way, still helpfull though. I'll edit my question and add more context to were I would like to go with this.

Comment: @Bas If your edit will brake my answer you should ask new question